# Block sliding down an inclined type of energy transformation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, potential-energy

when we have a box sliding down a ramp, does the gravitational potential energy directly transform into internal energy? I mean doesn't it firstly turn into kinetic energy then turns to internal energy?

and how is it different from a situation involving a roller coaster traveling down a hill? 
is it going through the same energy transformation, like from gravitational potential energy to internal energy?

Comment: What do you mean by "internal energy"?

Comment: energy turning into heat in the floor

Comment: Internal energy is a very confusing term here, as it is more commonly used in thermodynamics

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking about a roller-coaster. What difference are you asking about?

Comment: Does the roller-coaster gain any internal energy? If so, how? ... I still have difficulty understanding what you are trying to ask when you make the comparison with a roller-coaster.  Do *you* think this is the same situation or different, and why?

Comment: I'm just writing the book's, which I'm studying, information, but it seems like that there is no space for beginners on this site. I know my question might seem dumb to you experts, but I'm just a student, and I really don't know why the rating is -4, why are you guys hating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is really about the nature of friction, rather than about gravitational potential energy.  Friction is pretty complicated. There is static friction (which must be overcome in order to get the box moving) and sliding (moving) friction.

To quote Wikipedia: "Dry friction arises from a combination of inter-surface adhesion, surface roughness, surface deformation, and surface contamination. The complexity of these interactions makes the calculation of friction from first principles impractical and necessitates the use of empirical methods for analysis and the development of theory."

Overcoming static inter-surface adhesion does NOT involve converting kinetic energy to heat or other forms of internal energy, because it occurs when the box is not moving.  In that case you could say that gravitational potential energy is converted more or less directly to internal energy (in the process of overcoming static friction).  But after the box is moving, you could say that gravitational energy is converted first to kinetic energy and then to internal energy in the box and the ramp.

If the ramp were perfectly smooth and instead of a sliding a box you rolled a cylinder down the ramp, there would be effectively no friction, and all of the gravitational energy would be converted more or less directly into kinetic energy: the energy of the linear motion center of mass of the cylinder, *plus* the kinetic energy due to rotation of the cylinder.

A roller coaster is a lot different from a sliding box.  Its wheels have bearings designed to minimize sliding friction, almost like setting the roller coaster cart on cylindrical rollers, and letting the rollers roll down the ramp with the cart.  So, the net friction for a roller coaster is much, much lower than the friction for a sliding box.

Comment: This does not seem to *directly* answer the question

Comment: Thank you for your beneficial answer, but the idea is still quiet ambiguous.